# save from data to multiple rows in wordpress db

Tags: arrays, database, wordpress

I'm trying the store multiple rows into a database. The number of fields will change. Below is the way that I use to store just one row.

NOTE: the saved data can NOT be saved in 1 row! The example show 4 x 4 inputs, so it should save the data into 4 rows!

// code

```
  <?php

  if(isset($_POST['save'])){
      $wpdb->insert('wp_table_name',
          array(
              'field_a' => $_POST['field_a'],
              'field_b' => $_POST['field_b'],
              'field_c' => $_POST['field_c'],
              'field_d' => $_POST['field_d']             
              ),
          array(
              '%s',
              '%s',
              '%s',
              '%s'
              )
          );
  }
  ?>

  <form>
      <input type="text" name="field_a[]"/>
      <input type="text" name="field_b[]"/>
      <input type="text" name="field_c[]"/>
      <input type="text" name="field_d[]"/>

      <input type="text" name="field_a[]"/>
      <input type="text" name="field_b[]"/>
      <input type="text" name="field_c[]"/>
      <input type="text" name="field_d[]"/>

      <input type="text" name="field_a[]"/>
      <input type="text" name="field_b[]"/>
      <input type="text" name="field_c[]"/>
      <input type="text" name="field_d[]"/>

      <button type="submit" name="save">Save</button>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_rows

$wpdb->insert(); is use to store 1 row

so call it x times ? (where x is your number of fields)